# Как правильно написать ArgumentResolver?

Tags: symfony

Всем доброго времени суток.

Обычно, пишу ArgumentValueResolver для создания ДТОшки из json'a

```
    public function resolve(Request $request, ArgumentMetadata $argument): Generator
{
    $data = $this->serializer->deserialize($request->getContent(), $argument->getType(), JsonEncoder::FORMAT);

    $violations = $this->validator->validate($data, null, $argument->getType());
    if ($violations->count()) {
        throw new ValidationException($violations);
    }

    yield $data;
}
```

Через сериалайзер происходит создание какой-то ДТО и валидация её.
Сейчас же мне потребовалось создать какой-то обработчик для реквеста с телом типа **form-data**

Знаю, что можно написать свой queryConvert, используя ParamConverterInterface, но он для ГЕТ параметров
Или можно просто добавить условия в существующий ArgumentValueResolver, и если приходит form-data, использовать другую логику создания ДТО?
**Итог:** Как правильно обработать заспрос с типом form-data и в контроллере сразу получать нужный объект.
P.S. Эти данные приходят не через форму

Answer (score 0):

Если тип `form-data` приходит в POST запросе, то все данные находятся в `$request->request`. Тогда пишите другой резолвер, где вместо deserialize используйте denormalize

```
class FormDataResolver implements ArgumentValueResolverInterface 
{
    public function supports(Request $request, ArgumentMetadata $argument)
    {
        // определяете, что $request содержит form-data
    }

    public function resolve(Request $request, ArgumentMetadata $argument)
    {
        $data = $this->serializer->denormalize($request->request->all(), $argument->getType());
        ...
    }
}
```

Или в том же резолвере проверяете тип реквеста и выбираете, какая операция применится.